# Declarative rendering of data do not work but v-model of the same data works

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

This may be a naive question.. But my 'message' attribute under my data do not work on the html when used as {{message}}

I tried the same 'message' attriute on v-model with a  tag and this works.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    </head>


    <body style="background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #2b9f9a, #2576AD)">
        <div id = "app">
            <h1>{{message}}</h1>
            <input id="ip" v-model="message">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app', 
            data: { 
            message: 'Première application VueJS'
          } 
        }); 

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there typo in `{message}}`? It should be `{{message}}`

Comment: My bad. It was {{message}}. I will edit the question.